# Vue JS Error when using v-for to get JSON key values from an object array

Tags: javascript, json, vuejs2

I am trying to parse a list of objects in a JSON payload into a table using Vue.js.

I want to take the keys from the first object in the array to create the table headings, the code below works and provides the correct values, but the problem is I keep getting this error message

The Error message

```
[Vue warn]: Error in render function: "TypeError: objectArray is null"

(found in <Root>)
```

The Html element

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th v-for="(value, key) in objectArray[0]">
            {{ key }}
        </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

The JSON payload

```
[
{ "field1": "value", "field2": "value", "field3": "value", "field4": "value", "field5": "value", "field6": "value", "field7": "value" },
{ "field1": "value", "field2": "value", "field3": "value", "field4": "value", "field5": "value", "field6": "value", "field7": "value" },
{ "field1": "value", "field2": "value", "field3": "value", "field4": "value", "field5": "value", "field6": "value", "field7": "value" } 
]
```

The Vue code to populate the object

```
var link = 'api/array';

new Vue ({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        objectArray: null
    },
    methods:{
        getObjectArray: function(){
            this.$http.get(link).then(function(response){
                this.objectArray = response.data;
            }, function(error){
                console.log(error.statusText);
            });
        }
    },
    mounted: function () {
        this.getObjectArray();
    }
});
```

Comment: The warning means your `objectArray` property is `null` when it's attempting to access the index at `0`. Are you loading this JSON data asynchronously?

Comment: Nope its not being loaded asynchronously. I can load the entire list at the same point with no problems. The issue only occurs when i specify an element in that array to use.  If i print out the object at that index using {{objectArray[0]}} there are no errors either

Comment: Can you show where you're setting `objectArray`?

Comment: I've added the code snippet for getting the array

Comment: The `this.$http.get` call is asynchronous and `objectArray` is initially `null`, thus the error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error is because the objectArray is null the first time and isn't a Array. Try this code to prevent the error until your request is loaded:

```
<thead v-if='objectArray'>
    <tr>
        <th v-for="(value, key) in objectArray[0]">
            {{ key }}
        </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

Comment: Ah thank you. Am I doing something wrong with the Vue setup if im having to check for nulls initially?

Comment: @user2120640 It depends on the situation and is probably up to personal preference or team standards. If you don't want to have to check via `v-if`, you could also initially set the `objectArray` to `[{}]`. Or you could create a computed property `fooObject` that returns the value of `objectArray[0]` if it exists or an empty object otherwise. Then you could just reference `fooObject` in the `v-for`.